# PHP ImageJPEG method but for Java

Tags: java, php, image, methods, jpeg

I'm looking for a Java solution to this. I need a Java method that behave exactly the same as php IMAGEJPEG method does.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a really good tutorial on saving images in Java http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/. 
The specific class you want to look at is ImageIO http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html
Finally, to adjust quality, take a look at this article http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/java/adjust-jpeg-image-compression-quality-when-saving-images-in-java